# Solana "delegate-stake" fails on devnet

Tags: validator, solana-cli, keypair, delegate, stake

When trying delegate stake using:

```
solana delegate-stake \
  --fee-payer ~/staker-wallet-keypair.json \
  --stake-authority ~/staker-wallet-keypair.json \
  <STAKE_ACCOUNT_PUBKEY> <VOTE_ACCOUNT_PUBKEY>
```

I always get an error saying `Error: keypair-pubkey mismatch`

For <STAKE_ACCOUNT_PUBKEY> I use pubkey of stake account

For <VOTE_ACCOUNT_PUBKEY> I use one of vote accounts gathered using `solana validators`

Any ideas what might be going on? I tried multiple different variants always resulting in the same error. Example above is direct copy of this tutorial (https://github.com/agjell/sol-tutorials/blob/master/staking-on-solana.md) which also fails